# How to resolve New Relic for Node.js halted startup due to an error: Error: Failed to connect to collector?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, mocha.js, newrelic

I've cloned a fully functioning repo. The project is in Typescript and I'm adding some unit tests using mocha. The project uses NewRelic and when I run the project I get the following error:

```
    PS C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer> npm start run

> wss@0.0.0 start C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer
> node --inspect=5858 -r ts-node/register ./src/index.ts "run"

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/e7008339-7856-4a71-9f54-acfbb1cdd93f
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
{"app_name":"Consumer","level":"info","message":"App is running on http://localhost:3000","label":"","timestamp":"2020-07-14T13:57:48.276Z"}
New Relic for Node.js halted startup due to an error:
Error: Failed to connect to collector
    at onStartConnect (C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer\node_modules\newrelic\lib\agent.js:237:18)
    at retry (C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer\node_modules\newrelic\lib\collector\api.js:110:14)
    at onPreConnect (C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer\node_modules\newrelic\lib\collector\api.js:162:14)
    at Immediate.setImmediate (C:\Users\ENV\Projects\Consumer\node_modules\newrelic\lib\collector\parse-response.js:62:24)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

I've done npm install. On other devices this project works just fine, so maybe I need to configure something differently on my local? I'm not sure. Also the license is correct and has been checked. Might anyone have suggestions on why I may be having this error and what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

npm install only retrieves the New Relic agent module, but you need to add the configuration like application name, and, more importantly, your license key for New Relic.

You can find all the details here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/install-nodejs-agent

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I removed **newrelic** folder from **nodemodules** directory and re-installed newrelic `npm install newrelic --save`
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this error message is a bit misleading; the 'halted startup' referenced here is only for the New Relic agent itself, your application should continue to boot normally.

That specific error should really only appear if you don't actually have a network connection, are you sure this device was online when this happened?